# Apache Oltu Spring Security OAuth2 and Google Integration

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, oltu

The reference being purely taken from following sites:-

- http://syntx.io/integrating-your-java-spring-mvc-webapp-with-facebook-doing-the-oauth-dance/
- http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/OAuth-2.0-implementation-in-Spring-Framework

I've developed String Security OAuth2 Facebook integration example, Now I'm looking forward to developed the **Security OAuth2 Google** (and later Github) integration example where AppID and Secret will be provided to get "access_token" and "refresh_token" etc to be used to access the protected resources like UserDetails etc..

So, first step will be register App on http://code.google.com/apis/console. So it gives me "Client ID" and "Client secret", also I've configured Redirect URI, Done !

Now I've started writing actual Apache OAuth client, but I'm not sure what parameters I need to provide (similarly I provide for Facebook Integration, those parameters were easily available on facebook,while doing google search, but not found for Google), **Please provide me suggestions what values should be given for the following blank parameters** -

I think I've provided enough information, so any guidance / help / links is appreciated.

```
OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
                .authorizationLocation("")
                .setClientId("3kT21Hlkzzt5eV1")
                .setRedirectURI("http://localhost:8080/apache-oltu/google/redirect")
                .setResponseType("")
                .setScope("")
                .buildQueryMessage();
```

The following code is developed for callback

```
private void getAccessToken(String authorizationCode) throws OAuthSystemException, OAuthProblemException {
        OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
                .tokenLocation("")
                .setGrantType()
                .setClientId("3kT21H5EO3zzt5eV1")
                .setClientSecret("1kT21Hdlkzzt5eV1")
                .setRedirectURI("http://localhost:8080/apache-oltu/google/redirect")
                .setCode()
                .buildBodyMessage();
```

Added the following code to get protected resources like user profile:

```
request= new OAuthBearerClientRequest("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile").
                    setAccessToken(oAuthResponse.getAccessToken()).
                    buildQueryMessage();
```

Answer (score 1):

See here for a complete example:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/oltu-user/201503.mbox/%3CA562FE5D3662044186474F4174F11DAE13044C639F@iowajhnex126.iowa.gov.state.ia.us%3E

Comment: I've modified the code and use the scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me), but I see it's not giving me profile data. Could you please help / guide ?

Comment: add scope "openId profile email" and in your configured client application enable this scopes as well. If in google console you have not enable google+ related socpes then google will not give you user information.

Comment: @prtk_shah: I use the .setScope("openId profile email"), still unable to get the profile details. could you please help me out ASAP?
Saqib: Thanks. Could you please provide more detailed details. It's not understanding which URL's you've used for.

Comment: you have to enable "Google+ API" in google developer console. go to https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0 and click on your project , in your project open "APIs and auth">APIs. search for Google+ API and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed **Apache Oltu and Spring integration** example and it's working fine at my end.

You need to enable the Google+ API as suggested by @prtk_shah. Thanks.

You need to go to the https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0 and click on your project, in my case it's "apache-oltu", in your open project find option "APIs and auth" --> APIs. search for Google+ API and enable it.

Here you should be able to see this screen.
[image]

So, I will modify your code below it should be like this:

(IMP) - Your client ID should be like this, For Ex: (755670439314-jcumfghnkmcm72hf40beikvoatknstml.apps.googleusercontent.com), Please make sure it is correct. Fyi - use as it is provided by google developer console

```
OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
                .authorizationLocation("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth")
                .setClientId("3kT21Hlkzzt5eV1.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .setRedirectURI("Give your projects redirect URI")
                .setResponseType("responsecode")
                .setScope("openId profile email")
                .buildQueryMessage();
```

The callback code should be:

```
private void getAccessToken(String authorizationCode) throws OAuthSystemException, OAuthProblemException {
        OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
                .tokenLocation("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
                .setGrantType(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .setClientId("give your complete client id")
                .setClientSecret("give your secret")
                .setRedirectURI("This will be your callback or Redirect URL (Give it correctly)")
                .setCode(authorizationCode)
                .buildBodyMessage();
```

Here is what I'm getting in my example, just wanted to show you

[image]

Hope this will be helpful.